# Creating MySQL Query But its not working and error occurs

Tags: mysql

I am trying to Create a Query Where i will Select whole Table1 and Filter Table1.DateColumn using Between clause to match ids in Table2.

Because Table1 has dates but table2 does not have.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 
WHERE Table1DateColumn 
BETWEEN '2015-03-01' AND LAST_DAY('2016-02-01')

INNER JOIN Table2 
ON Table1.ID's = Table2.ids;
```

Comment: `WHERE` goes after the `JOIN`.

Comment: You mean `SELECT * FROM Table1 
 INNER JOIN 
WHERE Table1DateColumn 
BETWEEN '2015-03-01' AND LAST_DAY('2016-02-01') Table2 
ON Table1.ID's = Table2.ids;`

Comment: No, the sequence is `SELECT ... FROM ... INNER JOIN ... ON ... WHERE ...  BETWEEN ... AND ...`

Comment: If it does not bother you can you please post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sequence of the SQL clauses is incorrect. The correct order of the clauses should be:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.IDs = Table2.ids
WHERE Table1DateColumn BETWEEN '2015-03-01' AND LAST_DAY('2016-02-01')
```

Comment: Thank you very much and i want to add in last that Table1.Id is not null. It should be added like this in the last `AND Table1.Id is not null` @The Impaler

Comment: @HSHO Yes, that's how you combine "predicates".